# IQueryable<???> for linq-to-sql product type

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

With linq-to-sql, is there a way to specify the type of a product of two ORM entities? Like,

```
internal IQueryable<???> GetFooBarQuery(DataContext context)
{
    return
        from foo in foos
        join bar in bars on ...
        select new { foo, bar };
}
```

only where `???` is a type compatible with further query refinement, and where `new { foo, bar }` is replaced with something equivalent, but of type `???`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have anonymous type directly returned as the type is defined at compilation time only.
You should create a class to hold your data (DTO).

```
internal class FooBarDto
{
    public Foo Foo { get; set; }
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }
}

internal IQueryable<FooBarDto> GetFooBarQuery(DataContext context)
{
    return
        from foo in foos
        join bar in bars on ...
        select new FooBarDto{ Foo = foo, Bar = bar };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try dynamic or object as your return type, however the best solution in my mind would be to create a new class for the return type and instead of creating the return object dynamically simply return a new instance of your newly created type.

You can combine your data from both queries into one object which could hold two public properties, of each of the return type from your queries

```
public class ExampleClass
{
      public foo myFooObject { get; set; }
      public bar myBarObject { get; set; }
}

select new ExampleClass { foo = something, bar = something };
```